# React useState not updating

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

I'm learning React and I know this subject has been covered by many questions, but they all are focused on the asynchronous nature of `useState`. I'm not sure if that's what's happening here. I also tried a version in combination with `useEffect`, and the result was the same.

I have a component where I'm listening to keypresses - user is trying to guess a word. Once the word is guessed, the `word` object is supposed to be replaced with another one and a new puzzle begins.

The component renders using the correct state (characters of the new word), but when trying the first guess of the second puzzle, the `word` object is still the original state object.

How can I update this `word` object correctly?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/karolskrobot/wordgame-so-question/tree/main)

Steps to reproduce in the [readme.md](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-gauss-knek1k?file=/README.md):

```
const WordFrame = () => {
    const [word, setWord] = useState(() => new Word 'apple');
    const [renderedCharacters, setRenderedCharacters] = useState(
        word.renderedCharacters
    );

    const keyDownHandler = (e: KeyboardEvent): void => {
        console.log(e.key);
        if (letters.includes(e.key)) {
            const correctGuess = word.processGuess(e.key);

            if (correctGuess) {
                setRenderedCharacters([...word.renderedCharacters]);
                
                // moving the following if block into useEffect with dependency on word.isGuessed and renderedCharacters doesn't help
                if (word.isGuessed) {
                    const newWord: Word = new Word('banana');
                    setWord(newWord);
                    setRenderedCharacters(newWord.renderedCharacters);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler);
        return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler);
    }, []);

    // useEffect(() => {
        // if (word.isGuessed) {
        //     const newWord = new Word('banana);
        //     setWord(newWord);
        //     setRenderedCharacters(newWord.renderedCharacters);
        // }
    // }, [word.isGuessed, renderedCharacters]);

    return (
        <div className='word-frame'>
            {renderedCharacters.map((c) => (
                <LetterFrame characterValue={c.value} key={c.id} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default WordFrame;
```

**Word.ts**

```
class Word {
    private readonly _unguessedCharacter: string = ' ';
    private readonly _characters: string[] = [];
    private _guessingIndex = 0;

    private _renderedCharacters: Character[] = [];
    public get renderedCharacters() {
        return this._renderedCharacters;
    }

    private _isGuessed: boolean = false;
    public get isGuessed(): boolean {
        return this._isGuessed;
    }

    constructor(wordString: string) {
        console.log(`Word.constructor called with parameter: ${wordString}`);
        this._characters = wordString.split('');
        this.setRenderedCharacters();
    }

    public processGuess(letter: string): boolean {
        const isSuccessfulGuess = (): boolean =>
            this._characters[this._guessingIndex].toLowerCase() ===
            letter.toLowerCase();

        const successful = isSuccessfulGuess();

        if (successful) {
            this._guessingIndex++;
            this.setRenderedCharacters();
        }

        if (this._guessingIndex > this._characters.length - 1) {
            this._isGuessed = true;
        }

        return successful;
    }

    private setRenderedCharacters(): void {
        this._renderedCharacters = [];

        this._characters.forEach((c, i): void => {
            if (i >= this._guessingIndex) {
                this._renderedCharacters.push(
                    new Character(this._unguessedCharacter)
                );
            } else {
                this._renderedCharacters.push(new Character(c));
            }
        });
    }
}

export default Word;
```

Comment: Where's the implementation of getNewWordString?

Comment: @youdateme Added. When debugging I'm getting new strings when calling the factory correctly.

Comment: Can you put this on a codesandbox or something similar? I have a hard time thinking about the code with no interaction.

Comment: @youdateme https://codesandbox.io/s/github/karolskrobot/wordgame-so-question/tree/main

Comment: What are the steps to reproduce the bug in the codesandbox?

Comment: Could you simplify the code in order for the audience to easily get the point?

Comment: @paulmelnikow steps added in the readme

Comment: Typed first word; nothing wrong. Tried to type the first letter of the next word and I get `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`. Do you get the same error?

Comment: @youdateme yes that's the problem, and the reason for that is that the `word` object is still the one created on the basis of the first string, the guessing index is it's length + 1 and so on

Comment: @Ron simplified a bit by removing the factory service, will look at simplifying further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `keyDownHandler` captures `word` from the initial render, then is only attached to `keydown` once. You need to remove and re-attach `keyDownHandler` every time `word` changes (remember that whenever you call `setWord`, React will trigger a re-render where `word` contains the new word value).

Here's the fix:

```
const WordFrame = () => {
    const [word, setWord] = useState(() => new Word('apple'));

    // ...

    const keyDownHandler = (e: KeyboardEvent): void => { /* ... */ };

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler);
        return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler);
    }, [word]); // <-- add `word` to the dependencies for this effect

    // ...
};
```

Now, every time `WordFrame` rerenders with a new `word`, it will attach a fresh copy of the `keyDownHandler` closure that captures the most recent value of `word`.

If you want to read more about this mechanic, I highly recommend Dan Abramov's (comprehensive) guide [here](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/). You can also Google "stale closure React useEffect" and find a few more good articles.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug without a codesandbox but I'm guessing since you want the useEffect to trigger when you do

`setRenderedCharacters([...word.renderedCharacters]);`

You should add `renderedCharacters` as the dependency

```
useEffect(() => {
         if (word.isGuessed) {
             const newWord = getWord();
             setWord(newWord);
             setRenderedCharacters(newWord.renderedCharacters);
         }
}, [word.isGuessed, renderedCharacters]);
```

Comment: nope. codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/karolskrobot/wordgame-so-question/tree/main